# Caret tracking in a ContentEditable or a Textarea copied to. Account for child div, span, img, p, br HTML tags and more

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm dabbling in jquery and javascript to get done what I need. At the heart of the problem is an emoji picker that I coded in PHP. It inserts emoji just fine, but it doesn't insert at the caret position. Every script I've found somehow fails to account for the html tags. The count is always wrong, so where the emoji is inserted can vary, sometimes in the middle of an html tag, which turns the editor box into a horrible hurricane-stricken site.

```js
<script>
/* VERSION 2 8/21/2022 */
function getCharacterOffsetWithin_final(range, node) {
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        node,
        NodeFilter.ELEMENT_NODE,
        function(node) {
            var nodeRange = document.createRange();
            nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
            return nodeRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, range) < 1 ?
                NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        },
        false
    );

    var charCount = 0, lastNodeLength = 0;

    if (range.startContainer.nodeType == 3) {
        charCount += range.startOffset;
    }

    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        charCount += lastNodeLength;
        lastNodeLength = 0;
        
        if(range.startContainer != treeWalker.currentNode) {
            if(treeWalker.currentNode instanceof Text) {
                lastNodeLength += treeWalker.currentNode.length;
            } else if(treeWalker.currentNode instanceof HTMLBRElement ||
                      treeWalker.currentNode instanceof HTMLImageElement  ||
                      treeWalker.currentNode instanceof HTMLSpanElement  ||
                      treeWalker.currentNode instanceof HTMLDivElement)
            {
                lastNodeLength++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return charCount + lastNodeLength;
}


var update = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("interim");
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    $(\'#cursorPos\').text(getCharacterOffsetWithin_final(range, el));
};
$("#commentsbox").on("mouseup keyup", update);
/* VERSION 2 END 8/21/2022 */

var interim = function() {
    $(\'#interim\').val($(this).text());
};

$(\'#commentsbox\').on("mousedown mouseup keydown keyup", interim);
```

```html
            <div class="input" role="textbox" contentEditable="true" data-placeholder="Comment here..." name="comment-content" style="word-break: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;font-size:x-large;padding:5px;text-align:left;display:inline-block;min-height:100px;width:95%;border:solid 0.75px '.$bordercolor.';" id="commentsbox" class="'.$_SESSION['theme'].'"></div>
            <div id="cursorPos"></div>
            <textarea id="interim" style="display:none;"></textarea>
            <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;display:none;padding:5px;text-align:left;min-height:20px;min-width:95%;border-left:solid 0.75px '.$bordercolor.';border-right:solid 0.75px '.$bordercolor.';" id="menubox" class="hiddencontrols">
                <span style="display:inline-block;height:100%;width:50px;" class="material-icons emojilist_tog"><img src="https://rellawings.com/emoji/blobdrool2.png" height="24px" \>arrow_drop_down</span><span class="material-icons" style="display:inline-block;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">format_quote</span><span style="display:inline-block;"><img src="https://rellawings.com/images/spoiler.png" height="20px" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="emojilist" style="display:none;width:300px;max-height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:1000000;text-align:center;">
                <div style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bolder;font-size:large;text-align:center;background-color:#292929;width:280px;padding:10px;">Emoji</div>
                <div style="position:relative;padding-left:8px;text-align:center;background-color:#1e1e1e;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;max-height:150px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">';
                    
                $emojifullpath = '/home/gwingdivineknight/rellawings.com/emoji/';
                $emojidir = 'https://rellawings.com/emoji/';
                $emojifiles = array_diff(scandir($emojifullpath), array('..', '.')); $i = 1;
                foreach ($emojifiles as &$value) {
                    $cleanname = basename($value,".png");
                    $body .= '<span style="display:inline-block;padding:3px;"><img src="'.$emojidir.$value.'" height="24px" id="emoji-'.$i.'" /></span>';
                    $body .= '
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    
                                    $("#emoji-'.$i.'").click(function(event){

                                        var emoimg = "<span style=\'display:inline;padding:4px;position:relative;bottom:-4px;\'><img src=\'https://rellawings.com/emoji/'.$value.'\' title=\':'.$cleanname.':\' alt=\':'.$cleanname.':\' height=\'24px\' /></span>";
                                        
                                        /* Proven To Work Except for Positioning */
                                        /*$(\'#commentsbox\').append(emoimg);

                                        var TotalContents = $(\'#commentsbox\'),
                                            fix = TotalContents.html().replaceAll("<br>", "");
                                        TotalContents.html(fix);*/

                                        cursorPos = $(\'#cursorPos\').html();

                                        var v = $(\'#commentsbox\').html();

                                        var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );                           
                                        var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );

                                        $(\'#commentsbox\').html(textBefore+ emoimg +textAfter);

                                    });
                                });
                                </script>
                            ';
                            $i++;
                }

$body .= '      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;display:none;padding:5px;text-align:right;min-height:40px;min-width:95%;position:relative;border:solid 0.75px '.$bordercolor.';" id="buttonsbox" class="hiddencontrols">
                <span style="display:inline-block;padding:5px;background-color:#292929;border-radius:7px;margin-right:4px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:6px;
                white-space:nowrap;color:#ffffff;cursor: pointer;position:relative;width:67px;" id="cancelbtn"><span class="material-icons" style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:2px;">clear</span>Cancel</span>
                <span style="display:inline-block;padding:5px;background-color:#292929;border-radius:7px;margin-right:4px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:6px;
                white-space:nowrap;color:#ffffff;cursor: pointer;position:relative;width:53px;" id="postbtn"><span class="material-icons" style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:2px;">create</span>Post</span>
            </div>
```

I'm at the end of my patience with attempting to get my emoji picker + contenteditable div work. The functions that I find don't return a perfect number of characters in tags and outside, so it's not able to place emoji accurately into the contenteditable div.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There's quite a lot of code here, most of it not relevant to actually doing the insertion. Can you extract a minimal reproducible example which we can run to see the problem? I'd suggest building in a specific emoji and put in the code which inserts it into the contenteditable element. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found! This lovely bit of code was contributed by a friend. Thanks to everyone for all the wonderful assistance! Here's the lovely solution! I'm sure it will help many people who get frustrated over the same sort of situation, looking for a simpler solution! <3

```
<script>
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(emojiHtml) {
    let sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            
            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            const el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = emojiHtml;
            let frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                node,
                lastNode;
            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            
            range.insertNode(frag);
            
            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(emojiHtml);
    }
}

function addToCommentsBox(emojiHtml) {
    const chatBox = document.getElementById("commentsbox");
    chatBox.focus();
    pasteHtmlAtCaret(emojiHtml);
}
</script>
```